# Override admin html of ordered items

Tags: adminhtml, sales-order, custom

I have created a custom order item and quote item named `logo`.

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_quote_item'), 'logo', 'varchar(255) NOT NULL');
   $installer->getConnection()->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_order_item'), 'logo', 'varchar(255) NOT NULL');
```

I can save the value into this while placing an order. But how to show this value below the product SKU on the order details page in admin.
I don't want to make changes to core files.
[image]

Comment: create this file in local folder by creating module

Comment: which file? I am able to override template files on frontend . I want to do it in admin view

Comment: if you can provide screen shot where you want it to display exactly?

Comment: I want add logo value below sku